# How would I add reactions to this without getting an error?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am wondering how I would add reactions to this code without getting any errors or something like that? I've already tried:

```
import discord
import os
import replit
import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("ready!")
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="over PRFL"))
  
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('<:NewEngland:759084416445710466> offer'):
    emoji1 = [':white_check_mark:']
    await message.add_reaction(emoji1)
    emoji2 = [':x:']
    await message.add_reaction(emoji2)
    member = message.mentions[0]
    await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} **offered by** <:NewEngland:759084416445710466
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: `discord.errors.InvalidArgument: emoji argument must be str, Emoji, or Reaction not NoneType.`

Comment: Can you please post your full code. The code how you posted will not work like that.

Answer (score 1):

As your error message states, you inputted invalid arguments to your `add_reaction` call.

Additionally, reactions don't function with the `:unicode_name_of_character:` syntax and you must either type it normally or find the unicode escape code (white check mark is `\u2705` and the red x is `\u274c`) of a reaction.
Try using:

```py
    emoji1 = '\u2705' # :white_check_mark:
    await message.add_reaction(emoji1)
    emoji2 = '\u274c' # :x:
    await message.add_reaction(emoji2)
```

(Sidenote: you can use the `hex(ord('somerandomcharacter')` to get the unicode escape you need. To copy them in from discord, copy the emoji, and then paste it into a code block, and then copy it again.)

Answer (score 0):

When you are assigning an emoji with `[]` to your variables you are creating a list.
Also you cant use shorthand for emojis with the discord bot.
So instead of `:white_check_mark:` you can use the emoji itself `✅`
Or you can use the unicode `'\u2705'`
So what you need to do is:

```
emoji1 = '✅'
```

or

```
emoji1 = '\u2705'
```